# Unable to concatenate in google scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new to writing scripts and I was experimenting.
I want to add time stamp along with the string.

```
 const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(SHEET_URL).getSheetByName(
    SHEET_NAME
);
const [header] = sheet.getRange('A1:1').getValues();
const STATUS = header.indexOf('Status');
var rowId = Number(e.parameter.row);
var date = new Date()
sheet.getRange(rowId + 1, STATUS + 1).setValue("Data Sent- " + date);
```

however, all I am getting the Status Column is **Data Sent-** and no time stamp.

please help where am i going wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You should convert the `date` to a `string` first, like this:

```
 var date = new Date();
  var timezone = 'GMC';
  var format= 'YYYY-mm-dd';
  var formatted_date = Utilities.formatDate(date,timezone , format);
sheet.getRange(rowId + 1, STATUS + 1).setValue("Data Sent- " + formatted_date);
```

Reference: [GAS Utilities Format Date](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String))